# Convert SQL Query to ActiveRecord Query Ruby on Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have this sql query

```
SELECT count(cast(created_at + interval '8h' AS date)),
       cast(created_at + interval '8h' AS date) AS request_date,
       count(*) AS request_count
FROM api_logs
WHERE api_key = '7bfe68e0-8b54-0137-f0f1-3311231232'
  AND cast(created_at + interval '8h' AS date) BETWEEN '2019-09-05' AND '2019-09-10'
GROUP BY request_date
ORDER BY request_date DESC;
```

I want to convert this to ActiveRecord query that I can use in my Rails console.

Answer (score 0):

@Sebastian Palma answer was correct but i faced some minor errors which i just tweaked to get the solution tht i wanted.

```
 ApiLog
   .where(api_key: '7bfe68e0-8b54-0137-f0f1-3311231232')
   .where("CAST(created_at + interval '8h' AS date) BETWEEN '2019-09-05' AND '2019-09-10'")
   .select(
     "count(cast(created_at + interval '8h' AS date)),
      cast(created_at + interval '8h' AS date) AS request_date, 
      count(*) AS request_count"
   )
   .group(:request_date)
   .order("request_date desc")
```